# does enabling ssl to mariadb and postgres databases introduce server overload or impact performance?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

what does enabling ssl introduce in the process of connection to database? i understand that handshaking introduces load but encryption doesn't. I am using the following code to enable ssl while connecting to database using create_engine in sqlalchemy:

```
uri = "{0}://{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(db_creds.get('scheme'),
                                                 self._get_auth_str(db_creds.get('username'),
                                                                    db_creds.get('password')),
                                                 db_creds.get('hostname'),
                                                 str(db_creds.get('port')),
                                                 db_creds.get('name'))
            ssl_args = {}
            if self.config['ssloption'].lower() == 'true':
                # connecting securely
                if db == 'mysql':
                    self.config['ssloption'] = 'required'
                    ssl_args = {
                        'ssl': {
                            'sslmode': str(self.config['ssloption'])
                        }
                    }
                if db == 'warehouse':
                    self.config['ssloption'] = 'require'
                    ssl_args = {
                        "sslmode": str(self.config['ssloption'])
                    }
                self._connections[db] = create_engine(uri, connect_args=ssl_args, encoding='utf8')
            else:
                # not connecting securely
                self._connections[db] = create_engine(uri, encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encrypting and decrypting data will certainly use CPU time.

To see if that performance impact would affect you substantially, run a performance test.

Usually, it is not a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

no, it doesn't affect the database server performance. It might just increase a very minor time-lag in establishing a connection, but server performance would remain as it was before.